# Eliminate the single quotes while printing the list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I am new to python and I am not getting how to print the list in which, the list should not contain ' while printing.

if give `print list` I am getting the result as `['xyz', 'ysfe']` I need to eliminate that single quotes.

Comment: You want to eliminate single quotes but leave the brackets? Why?

Comment: Something like `print('[{}]'.format(', '.join(l)))` would work.  I don't really see the point though.

Comment: Please do post the reason you are looking for such a solution. Also before asking a question, please do search stackoverflow if its already answered. It makes this community a better place and you also learn along the way. Thanks.

Comment: (Don't add tags willy-nilly. Your example is an error in Python 3.x.) The function `print` expects a *string*. If you give it something entirely different – "here, have a list and see what you can do with it" – it calls the object's `__str__` method to get a string rep. And you cannot influence that.

Comment: Note: avoid using the variable name of `list` as this will replace the builtin Python function `list()`

Answer (score 2):

try this, it will work

```
mylist = ['abc', 'def', 'brt']
print ('[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, mylist)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a=['xyz', 'ysfe']
print(str(a).replace("'",''))
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['xyz', 'ysfe']
print(str(lst).translate(str.maketrans('', '', "'")))
```

try this, it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['xyz', 'ysfe']
s = {39: None}
print(str(a).translate(s))
```

Comment: Add a little context by saying why your code works. That way it might help the OP and others as well.